# Strange javascript behaviour (assignments)

Tags: javascript, swap, operator-precedence

**Swap two numbers**

C++:

```
int a = 3;
int b = 5;
a^=b^=a^=b;
printf("%d, %d\n", a, b); //5, 3
```

PHP:

```
$a = 3; $b = 5;
$a^=$b^=$a^=$b;
echo "$a, $b\n"; //5, 3
```

Javascript:

```
> a=3;b=5;a^=b^=a^=b;[a,b]
[ 0, 3 ]
```

Why? Looks like all variables initialized before all expression executed...

Comment: Your C++ example header should say "Some C++, if you're lucky", since it uses undefined behavior.

Comment: :), I know C++ bad, just write sample and compile for a check)
I'm lucky))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your assignment in JS is equivalent to

```
a = a ^ (b = b ^ (a = a ^ b));
```

and that is evaluated from left to right and for a we get

```
3 ^ (5 ^ (3 ^ 5))
```

So an easy fix would be to write

```
a = (b ^= (a ^= b)) ^ a;
```

Welcome to the world of JS =)

Answer (score 1):

In ES6, you can simply [use destructing assignment](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3adestructuring):

```
var a = 3
var b = 5
[a, b] = [b, a]
```

which behaves as expected.

Comment: The question was why Javascript behavior differs, not how to swap numbers.

Comment: @IngoBürk The behaviour's a lot less strange if you use a mechanism explicitly intended for this purpose. Also: the poster would be a better position to comment on their own intentions than you.

Comment: thanks, @IngoBürk is right, swap is not my target here; But about yours: where can I test ES6? I have ES5 in all my browsers(FF, Chrome on Ubuntu) and even in my nodejs interpretator)

Comment: I agree that using this construct even in a fixed way is a terrible idea. But his question was very clear "Why?", not "How should I do it instead?". Besides, for an actual fix, ES6 is a nice hint, but it's not like you can actually use that in productive systems yet unless you have a limited target group.

Comment: @vp_auth Node with the harmony parameter runs in ES6 mode, chrome it's a flag.